# set up camunda rest api

Tags: rest, tomcat, camunda

I want to use the camunda rest api (local), but I realy can't figure out how to set up the environment... .

First I downloaded the tomcat distribution from [here](http://camunda.org/download/) (V. 7.2.0) and the prepackaged eclipse with BPMN 2.0 Modeler from [here](http://camunda.org/download/modeler/).

I modelled a process, startet the server (`start-camunda.bat`) and deployed it (copied `.war` to [...camunda\server\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps](http://camunda%5Cserver%5Capache-tomcat-7.0.50%5Cwebapps)). 
It went well on local tasklist http://localhost:8080/camunda/app/tasklist/default/#/login and cockpit http://localhost:8080/camunda/app/cockpit/default/).

I also downloaded the `engine-rest` from "Maven Nexus Server" ([Install the REST API web application](http://docs.camunda.org/7.2/guides/installation-guide/tomcat/#web-applications-install-the-rest-api-web-application)). Now, if I call the engine (http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/engine), I got the following `.json`: `[{"name":"default"}]`

What to do next? I realy don't know (I'm new in camunda...)

Comment: What do you want to do with the rest-api?

Comment: hm yeah, I'm not realy sure... I want to handle the process I designed the workflow for. I want to get and send dataobjects (like snapshots of current state) and to respond the state and next step of the process. Is this a possible use case of camunda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your setup seems to be fine. But please note that the camunda REST API is a backend which you can access with a client. Currently there doesn't exists a camunda Java REST client. So you have to implement it by your self. If you are aware of that a good starting point is the [camunda REST documentation](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/rest/). Besides Java there exists a [Javascript SDK](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-sdk-js) which you could use to access the REST API.

Comment: Javascript SDK with angularJS sounds nice. Is there any tutorial (just found an example app here: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/sdk-js)

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest an alternative: use a docker image for Camunda. It's official and works like a charm. You can set it up in 5 mins tops and then use an API client like postman to access Camunda's API via http://localhost:8080/engine-rest.
I had the same problem as yours and found a docker solution much easier than installing Camunda and all related dependencies myself only having to troubleshoot them later. Here's the link to the official docker image if you're interested:
https://hub.docker.com/r/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform

Or enter these 2 commands from terminal and you'll be golden:

```
docker pull camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:latest

docker run -d --name camunda -p 8080:8080 camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:latest
```

Open URL with browser: http://localhost:8080/camunda-welcome/index.html

username/password: admin/admin